# Unexpected element: CDATA soapUI maven plugin

Tags: json, rest, maven, soapui

I'm writing tests for a rest API. I'm using property and property transfer.

When I run my TestCase using SoapUI, everything goes fine. However, when I run it using maven and the com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1 I got this error:

```
Status: FAILED
Time Taken: 64
Size: 0
Timestamp: Fri Dec 21 14:15:12 GMT+01:00 2018
TestStep: Property Transfer 1
Error:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.PropertyTransferException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA

----------------- Messages ------------------------------
Error performing transfer [city] - error: Unexpected element: CDATA
----------------------------------------------------
city transferred [[error: Unexpected element: CDATA]] from [Personal_data.city] to [eligibility.Request]
------------ target path -------------
$..city
```

I'm thinking of using a Groovy script to do my properties transfers but first, I would realy like to understand why I have this error and if there is a way to fix it who doesn't involve a Groovy script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking and looking again, I finally manage to solve the issue:

The problem was that I was using SoapUI 5.4.0 with a (very) old version of soapui-maven-plugin. So, I just change the version of the soapUI plugin in maven to match the one of my SoapUI interfaces and it's now working fine.